# Is it possible to change angular material dialog default options?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Angular material dialogs have `clickOutsideToClose: false` by default and I always want it to be true for all dialogs in my application; is there a way to change the default options of `$mdDialog`, without modifying angular material's files? There are additional methods for `$mdDialogProvider`, but they don't seem to be intended for external use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. angular-material architecture doesn't expose these default options.

I've seen suggestions of using a decorator on `$mdDialog` and rewrite the method `$mdDialog.show()` in order to insert custom default options, bud this solution is very ugly because you would also have to make it work with `Preset`s which, for reasons I don't imagine, have a different mechanism for passing options. i.e. they have a `_options` attribute that is used instead.

I wish angular-material patterns were a bit more practical, and expose more elements, like these options, or even (unrelated) the default presets controller for example.